# Doctrine DQL Select record matching name or one of a list of aliases

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I'm struggling to improve a simple DQL query by matching multiple possible values.

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('circuit');
    $qb->where('circuit.name like ?1' )
        ->orWhere('circuit.alias like "?1"')
        ->setParameters(array(1 => $circuitName));
```

One record is:

Name: Spa Francorchamps
Alias: Spa, Spa-Francorchamps, Circuit de Spa-Francorchamps, Circuit de Spa Francorchamps

I need to expand the logic for the orWhere( line to look for one value in a comma-separated list.

Setting up a one to many table to handle this seems like overkill as the lookup will only be used on data entry.

Steve

Comment: Can you explain better what does not work with your current DQL? It seems fine to me.

Comment: I want to change the circuit.alias field into a comma separated list of aliases so that any of the stored aliases will match. Something like 
  where ( ?1 in explode(circuit.alias,','))